# System Idle Detection in windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop-application

I want an application that show message if user is inactive for certain minutes.

I have googled it and got solutions but it was hard to understand for me and I don't know how to use that code,

It would be appreciated if someone provides me some article that show step by step procedure to detect the inactivity of user and show the message in windows application c#.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy to do using the Windows API call [`GetLastInputInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo), assuming you can do so. Here's a sample wrapper class for it:

```
public sealed class UserActivityMonitor
{
    public UserActivityMonitor()
    {
        _lastInputInfo.CbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(_lastInputInfo);
    }

    /// <summary>Determines the time of the last user activity (any mouse activity or key press).</summary>
    /// <returns>The time of the last user activity.</returns>

    public DateTime LastActivity => DateTime.Now - this.InactivityPeriod;

    /// <summary>The amount of time for which the user has been inactive (no mouse activity or key press).</summary>

    public TimeSpan InactivityPeriod
    {
        get
        {
            GetLastInputInfo(ref _lastInputInfo);
            uint elapsedMilliseconds = (uint)Environment.TickCount - _lastInputInfo.DwTime;
            elapsedMilliseconds = Math.Min(elapsedMilliseconds, int.MaxValue);
            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(elapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Struct used by Windows API function GetLastInputInfo()</summary>
    struct LastInputInfo
    {
        public int  CbSize;
        public uint DwTime;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LastInputInfo plii);

    LastInputInfo _lastInputInfo;
}
```

To use this, just create an instance of the class and check the `InactivityPeriod` property periodically (for example, by using a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0)).

Comment: I understood the code, but where do I have to put this code, I mean in program.cs file or somewhere else.

Comment: You would just add it in a new class to your application in a separate code file, as you would any other class that you write.